# Do dead allies gain experience?

Tags: super-mario-rpg

In Super Mario RPG, do dead allies gain experience? Typically in SquareEnix (then Square) games, dead allies receive no XP. But in this game, the victory pose at the end of the battle includes **all** team members, whether they were dead or not, and after a successful battle, even dead allies are revived with 1 HP.

Comment: I've typically seen allies that get revived with 1 hp after battle get experience while allies that do not get revived after battle do not. (Square games also tend to follow this pattern in my experience.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they do.

It's always fun to use a [TVTropes link](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/Supermariorpg) as reference:

> [After Combat Recovery](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AfterCombatRecovery): Dead characters are revived with 1 HP *and even gain experience* at the end of battle.